# bead on rotating wire, constraint force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I'm asked to find the force that a horizontal wire  that rotates with constant velocity $\omega$ exerts on a bead on it, neglegting gravity.

**Attempt:**

Using two coordinates: $r$ as the distance from the center of rotation and $\theta$ as the angle of rotation and the constraint $f(\theta,t) = \theta - \omega t = 0$ I find that the Lagrangian is:

$L = \dfrac{1}{2}m ( \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 )$

Because $P_\theta = mr^2 \dot{\theta}$ and
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = 1$, I find that the constraint force is:

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(mr^2 \dot{\theta}) = \lambda \implies \lambda \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = 2mr\dot{r}\omega$

Where I've used that $\dot{\theta} = \omega$

The result for $\lambda$ is wrong since the force exerted by the wire (which I assume is this force of constraint) is actually the Coriolis force which is $F=2m\dot{r}\omega$ (one can find this using Newton's law in non inertial frames).

what's wrong in my formulation? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is you are taking the derivative w/r to a dimensionless variable $\theta$ rather than something with unit of length like $x$.  In other words, don't you need $(\partial f/\partial\theta)/r$?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering. I see that solves the issue, and looking at my notes from class I found that on a different example $F_\theta = -\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}$ that has the same form that you're suggesting. But, can you elaborate on why this is so??

Comment: I expanded as an answer... a bit rough but I hope will give you a good feel for what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a perennial difficulty in problems involving angular variables that some length unit goes MIA.  When you think of the derivative of a momentum as you do here, you really are thinking of something like
$$
F=\frac{d}{dt}p_x
$$
where the momentum $p_x$ has units of [kg][m]/[s].  You need momentum to have such units or else $F$ will not have the usual units of [kg][m]/[s]$^2$.

The problem with your $p_\theta$ is that is has units [kg][m]^2/[s].  This is because $\theta$ is dimensionless, or equivalently does not have units of length.  *Roughly speaking*, the correct variable to use in your case is $r\theta$ rather than $\theta$ itself, so that $r\theta$ is a length much like $x$ has units of length.  This is usually implemented by inserting factors of $1/r$ after derivatives w/r to $\theta$ are taken, basically using $\partial f/\partial (r\theta)$ with $r$ kept constant.  (This is a highly informal and hand-wavy explanation but it gives you the flavour of the argument, which is based on correct dimensionality of various factors.)

Thus, in an expression like
$$
F=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{dU}{d\theta}\sim -\frac{dU}{dx} \tag{1}
$$
you have multiplied the derivative w/r to the dimensionless variable $\theta$ by a factor of $1/r$ so the denominator $(rd\theta)$ has units of length like the denominator $dx$ in Eq.(1).

The same kind of reasoning applies to your expression for $\lambda$.  In terms of Cartesian coordinates you would need $df/dx$ so here you need to divide your $df/d\theta$ by $r$ to make the units right.

This kind of issue regularly occurs when angular or other dimensionless variables are used.  You can spot the extra $r$ factors that make "the dimensions right" in various expressions such as the Laplacian or various derivatives in curvilinear coordinates.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, it didn't even cross my mind to check dimensions and I see that the reason is related to the length factors that arise in orthogonal coordinates. btw, great music! ;)

Comment: yes it's precisely related to the nasty factors that appear in curvilinear orthogonal coordinates...